# How do I update Growtopia faster?

Tags: growtopia

I want to update to Version 2.3.3 easily, but the way Growtopia does it always leads to an unknown tab! I have to go onto the Growtopia website to download the newest version and the trash the other one. Is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a setting in your browser that prevents pages from auto-downloading. In my case, I am able to download the update via there.

Answer (score 1):

it depends what you are updating Growtopia on. If you are having difficulties updating the game try re-installing the game.

If you are having slow download speeds try plugging in an ethernet cable into your computer or getting closer to your router.

I have the same problem you are having and I'm using a MacBook Pro 2019. Currently there is no alternative to re-installing the updated version and uninstalling the older version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling amazonaws.com an unknown tab, you're wrong - it's just a server where Growtopia is storing the file. If the file downloaded from that server is working, just use it and don't worry about writing out the address yourself.